# Supplying power to arduino by 5V and 2A adapter

Tags: arduino-uno, power, electronics

Can I power my Arduino using a 5V/2A adapter by connecting it through the USB port?

More precisely, I have to run a module requiring 200mA but the aim is to make the laptop independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amps are not "forced" through a circuit like volts are. A closed circuit draws as much power (in amps) as it needs, so the only problem you could ever have is having too *little* current and not too much. Seeing as your module draws 200ma 2 amps to power it is plenty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the second half of your question is saying, but:

> can i power my Arduino by 5 volt 2 amp adapter by connecting it through the usb port

Yes, you can.